# Comparison between two Categorical Variables

Tags: python, statistics, data-science

I have two Categorical Variables (Gender and Health). Gender can take values male and female whereas Health can take values 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 depending on the level of health (1 is less healthy, 2 is better healthy than 1, ..., 5 is the healthiest)

For the following Data Set, I need to decide if Women are healthier than Men.

[image: See dataset]

I know that for Categorical variables there is ChiSquare test for Difference between Two (Or more) proportions and ChiSquare Test of Independence. But it appears that none of these two tests would be able to compare two variables. Please advise how should I go for the needed comparison.

-Beejal

Answer (score 0):

you need to create 2 lists:

```
men = [45,70,178,92,26]
women = [36, 67, 329, 147, 20]
```

then you need to multiply the first number of the list by one, the second by two and so on. you also need two variables which you will compare later

```
j = 0
men_health = 0
women_health = 0
for i in range (1,5):
    men_health = men_health + men[j] * i
    women_health = women_health + women[j] * i  
    j =+ 1
```

finaly you will compare your two variables:

```
if men_health > women_health:
    print ("men are more healthy!")
elif men_health < women_health:
    print ("women are more healthy!")
```